# How to create a data ranged chart in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm really struggling to understand how to show a chart in Google sheet that automatically shows the last 7 items. I'm basically trying to create a dashboard. Ideally, I'd like to be able to select a range like last 7 days, last 30 days, month on month (6 months), month on month (12 months), by a quarter

[image: Table]

I want a chart that will show A,B,C,D,E,F and G all in one chart.

Comment: are you sure you need a chart/graph - https://www.google.com/search?q=chart&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X  - share a copy of your sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H1CpwHqNiSGIrqARr7whHp7_3wds6Oys1CfjBqrS5tk/edit?usp=sharing

Yes need a graph